# Cannot generate key in Android keystore

Tags: java, android, security, keystore, android-keystore

We are currently experiencing an issue where sometimes when a user installes our app, the app tries to access and generate a key in the keystore but the keystore throws this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: could not generate key in keystore
        at android.security.AndroidKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(AndroidKeyPairGenerator.java:100)
        at java.security.KeyPairGenerator$KeyPairGeneratorImpl.generateKeyPair(KeyPairGenerator.java:275)
```

We think it has to do with the unlock pattern off the phone does not unlock the keystore, and/or a device administrator locks the keystore.

This is how the keystore is created and how the keys are generated:

```
public SecretKeyWrapper(Context context, String alias) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    mCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
    keyStore.load(null);

    if (!keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {
        generateKeyPair(context, alias);
    }

    final KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry entry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(alias, null);
    mPair = new KeyPair(entry.getCertificate().getPublicKey(), entry.getPrivateKey());
}

private static void generateKeyPair(Context context, String alias) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    final Calendar start = new GregorianCalendar();
    final Calendar end = new GregorianCalendar();
    end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 100);

    final KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
            .setAlias(alias)
            .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + alias))
            .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
            .setStartDate(start.getTime())
            .setEndDate(end.getTime())
            .build();

    final KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
    gen.initialize(spec);
    gen.generateKeyPair();
}
```

Does anyone know how to:

- Lock the keystore as an device administrator?
- Unlock the keystore when it has been locked by a device administrator?
- Or reproduce this issue in another way?

Comment: Show the code of how you are creating the Keystore.

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 11):

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: could not generate key in keystore`

hope 1st exception will solved by following code below:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
ks.load(null);
KeyStore.Entry entry = ks.getEntry(alias, null);

ks.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(password))
```

Unlock the keystore when it has been locked by a device administrator:

`KeyStore` can appear locked not only on pre-ICS devices. The simplest way to get `KeyStore` locked is:

1. Initialize KeyStore by setting KeyGuard (pattern, pin, or password on the Screen Lock)
2. Add keys or whatever you store in the KeyStore
3. Go to Settings > Security and change Screen Lock to something "not secure", for example, Slide.
4. Reboot your device.

After the device is booted, KeyStore will be LOCKED. `com.android.credentials.UNLOCK` intent will start `com.android.settings.CredentialStorage` activity, which, in turn, will show UnlockDialog, prompting for a password.

```
 * KeyStore: LOCKED
 * KeyGuard: OFF/ON
 * Action:   old unlock dialog
 * Notes:    assume old password, need to use it to unlock.
 *           if unlock, ensure key guard before install.
 *           if reset, treat as UNINITALIZED/OFF
```

You can just generate a master key and store it as a private file, other apps won't be able to read it, so you'll be fine on non-rooted devices. This is the approach recommended on the Android Developers Blog:: http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2013/02/using-cryptography-to-store-credentials.html

Same question answer: [Android android.credentials.UNLOCK Initializing keystore without password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22666435/android-android-credentials-unlock-initializing-keystore-without-password/25951533#25951533)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jamil. I can't see however how calling the `KeyStore.getEntry(...)` method with a password makes sense given that the KeyStore entry was not created with a password (see the `KeyPairGenerator. generateKeyPair()` method invocation in the question). Please explain.

Comment: This answer is copied from this other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25951533/4473512. An honest approach should have been linking that answer giving credit to the author.

Comment: @Manzotin I don't think so. Same answer but different way. Btw I added link. Thanks.